# Hints find $Z$ so that $n \min\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}\xrightarrow{d} Z$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ while $(X_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ are independent and uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,1]$ and define $M_{n}:=\min\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}$.

Find a $Z$ so that $n M_{n}\xrightarrow{d} Z$

Solution:

If we can show $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(nM_{n}>z)=P(Z>z)$ then it immediately follows by the definition of the cdf that $\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X_{n}}=F_{Z}$

$P(nM_{n}> z)=P(nX_{1} > z,...nX_{n}>z)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}P(nX_{1}>z)=(P(nX_{i}>z))^{n}=(\int_{\frac{z}{n}}^{1}1dx)^n=(1-\frac{z}{n})^{n}1_{z \in [0,n]}$

For $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac{z}{n})^{n}=e^{-z}$

So we can choose $Z$~$\exp({-z})$ where $z \in [0, n]$ such that

$nM_{n} \xrightarrow{d} Z$

Is this correct?

Comment: Check: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample

Comment: Unfortunately, since you do not have a sum/average, you cannot use central limit theorem here. Try computing the distribution function directly and take $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$, compute $P(nM_n > z)$.

> $$P(nM_n > z) = (1 - \frac{z}{n})^n \cdot 1_{z \in [0, n]}.$$

Then
$$P(Z > z) = \lim_{z \to \infty} P(n M_n > z) = \cdots$$
and hopefully you recognize the resulting distribution.

Comment: How did you get $P(nM_{n} > z)=(1-\frac{z}{n})^{n}1_{z \in [0,n]}$? The cdf of $P(M_{n} > \frac{z}{n})=\int_{ \frac{z}{n}}^{\infty}1dx$

Comment: @SABOY $M_n$ is the minimum, it is not uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: I corrected my question/answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @SABOY "$Z \sim \exp(-z)$ where $z \in [0, n]$" does not make sense for a number of reasons: is $\exp(-z)$ a CDF? PDF? we usually don't use the $\sim$ notation with a CDF or PDF anyway. Also, your answer should not depend on $n$ since you are taking the limit as $n \to \infty$. But you are on the right track.

Comment: No it's supposed to  show $Z$  is exponentially distributed

Comment: @SABOY Yes, that is the answer, but "$Z \sim \exp(-z)$ where $z \in [0, n]$" is not the same as "$Z$ follows the exponential distribution" (and with what parameter?)

Comment: I would with parameter $-1$ but I am not sure, i.e. $X$ ~ $-\exp(-1)$

Comment: @SABOY Slow down and think carefully. You have $P(Z > z) = e^{-z}$ for $z \ge 0$. What distribution satisfies this property?

Comment: It would be: $X$ follows the distribution $\exp{(1)}$ as $P(Z<z)=1-e^{-z}$ and the cdf for any random variable $Y$ ~ $\exp{\lambda}$ is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$

Comment: @SABOY Yes. (Except it's $Z$, not $X$.)